# Why is my MacBook apparently waking up during the night?

Tags: macbook

I have a [bit of Java code](http://joereddington.com/1421/2013/12/02/keeping-track-of-time/) that keeps track of the active window of my mac.  It produces output like this:

```
2013-12-02_20:08:36Google Chrome:putting code in wordpress - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:08:36Google Chrome:putting code in wordpress - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:09:18Google Chrome:Writing Code in Your Posts « WordPress Codex
2013-12-02_20:09:33Google Chrome:wordpress java code with syntax highlighting - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:09:37Google Chrome:wordpress java code with syntax highlighting - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:09:37Google Chrome:wordpress java code with syntax highlighting - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:10:19Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:10:35Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:10:38Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:10:38Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:11:20Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:11:36Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
```

But I've noticed that during the night, with the laptop closed it produces the occasional other entry...

```
2014-10-08_22:45:48firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_00:15:59firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_02:04:10firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_03:52:21firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_05:40:30firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_07:28:38firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_08:48:28Calendar:Calendar//this one is me *actually* opening the laptop in the morning.
```

This doesn't happen every night - but I'm pretty sure there's nothing obvious that I'm doing that says "hey, wake up every 100 or so minutes so that the logger can catch you"

EDIT:

and, indeed, the next night...

```
2014-10-13_21:17:41Finder
2014-10-13_21:18:43Finder
2014-10-14_00:34:14TeamViewer:Computers & Contacts
2014-10-14_02:35:04TeamViewer:Computers & Contacts
2014-10-14_04:35:56TeamViewer:Computers & Contacts
2014-10-14_08:15:06TeamViewer:Computers & Contacts
2014-10-14_08:16:07Finder
2014-10-14_08:17:42Finder
```

any ideas?

Comment: He want to take a nightly jogging :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Java logging code pretty cool; very interesting honestly. That said this is still hard to say without fully understanding what your logs mean. But looking at these log entries as a control example:

```
2013-12-02_20:08:36Google Chrome:putting code in wordpress - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:08:36Google Chrome:putting code in wordpress - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:09:18Google Chrome:Writing Code in Your Posts « WordPress Codex
2013-12-02_20:09:33Google Chrome:wordpress java code with syntax highlighting - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:09:37Google Chrome:wordpress java code with syntax highlighting - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:09:37Google Chrome:wordpress java code with syntax highlighting - Google Search
2013-12-02_20:10:19Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:10:35Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:10:38Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:10:38Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:11:20Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2013-12-02_20:11:36Google Chrome:Add New Post ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
```

Compared to these lines you show as part of the perceived issue:

```
2014-10-08_22:45:48firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_00:15:59firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_02:04:10firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_03:52:21firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_05:40:30firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_07:28:38firefox:Edit Page ‹ Joe Reddington — WordPress
2014-10-09_08:48:28Calendar:Calendar//this one is me *actually* opening the laptop in the morning.
```

It seems to me that WordPress might be using Ajax calls in the browser window to pull content on a sporadic basis. So if you have your WordPress administrator screen loaded in FireFox, even with your system sleeping, FireFox is still running the JavaScript as a required for the Ajax process and that is what you are seeing.

The non-standard times point to some completely outside force making WordPress behave like that.  Perhaps—for example—a user or crawler is accessing your site in the middle of the night, WordPress logs it & then when the Ajax calls happen, FireFox updates your admin panel.